# Statistics; looking for a practical example-based book

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for an example-based 2nd year or thereabouts undergraduate statistics textbook in the style of Engineering Maths by Ken Stroud (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Stroud-Engineering-Mathematics/dp/0387912185 easily my favourite maths text book). At the moment I feel I've been exposed to lots of statistical tests, but I'm not confident of using any of them (or knowing the correct one to use) in anger on real-world problems.

If it could cover Bayesian probability as well, that would be excellent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like [Devore and Berk](http://books.google.com/books?id=cv3pcEJ7amMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=mathematical%20statistics%20with%20applications&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Gm_zU9sqssqxBP2QgJgO&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=mathematical%20statistics%20with%20applications&f=false). It assumes univariate and *some* multivariate, but its substantial enough to be useful after you graduate (not a lot of overly theoretical minutae) and they use real data sets.